# Multiple "if" Statements?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

If I wanted to hold SHIFT **and** right-click to perform a function, what would I need to change here?

JAVASCRIPT

```
function myfunction(e) {
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
if (e.shiftKey==1) {
//dostuff
}
}
```

HTML

```
<input onContextMenu="myfunction(e)" />
```

Comment: What is `Input.GetMouseButtonDown`?

Comment: Is `Input.GetMouseButtonDown` from [Unity](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html)?

Comment: Doesn't `onContextMenu` assume that you right-clicked on it?  What if you just had `if(e.shiftKey){}`?

Comment: Yes it does he just needs to checK e.shiftKey

Comment: Shouldn't `onContextMenu="myfunction(e)"` be `onContextMenu="myfunction(event)"`?

Comment: I'm assuming that `onContextMenu` gets called before the event listener in `Input.GetMouseButtonDown`, so you'd probably need to change it `onKeyDown` or something similar.

Comment: Also when you add an event listener only add your function (with no parameters)

Comment: @megawac: No.  Adding parameters is totally fine.

Comment: @RocketHazmat No its not in that context - its going to reference the return of myfunction when called with undefined

Comment: @megawac: What's going to reference what?  I don't understand what you're saying, sorry.

Comment: @RocketHazmat `<input onContextMenu="myfunction(e)" />` will have onContextMenu point to undefined as `myfunction(undefined)` => `undefined`

Comment: @megawac: When you set the `onContextMenu` attribute, you pass it JavaScript code to be executed when the event is ran.  You're thinking of `element.onContextMenu = myfunction(e)`.  That would set `element.onContextMenu` to `undefined`.  `onContextMenu="myfunction(event)"` is correct.

Comment: @user2811882: `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(3)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.which` corresponds to the mouse button pressed. 3 is a right-click.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/cjc343/Fns7g/) a fiddle which shows how you might test for a shift-right-click on an input.

Comment: Assuming he's using jQuery

Comment: @megawac: The question *is* tagged `jquery`.

Comment: He tagged it with jQuery, so I assumed he is. That said, it should be trivial to use pure JS instead to get the element and add a listener.

Comment: I will use jquery if it is the only option, but trying to avoid it just on preference.  SEE EDITS, sorry.

Comment: [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/cjc343/Fns7g/1/) the same thing with the trivial changes needed to make it pure JS.

Comment: Thanks, I was leaving out `console.log('met')` when I originally tried this.  Very appreciated!!

Answer (score 3):

The `onContextMenu` event is only triggered when you right-click on something, so lose the check for which mouse button was pressed.  Just check `e.shiftKey`.

```
function myfunction(e){
    if(e.shiftKey){
        // Do Stuff
    }
}
```

Also, make sure you pass the `event` to the function:

```
<input onContextMenu="myfunction(event)" />
```

Or better yet, don't use inline event handlers, and bind the event in JavaScript with `addEventListener`.

**EDIT**: You can also use an `onclick` event, and check for right-click (should be `2`):

```
function myfunction(e){
    if(e.button === 2 && e.shiftKey){
        // Do Stuff
    }
}
```

Then do:

```
<input onClick="myfunction(event)" />
```

Comment: Remind him to add the event properly (he's calling it with the event)

Comment: @megawac: Right, ok :)

Comment: @user2811882: That still doesn't change what's in my answer.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Are you suggesting that I use... `<input onClick="myfunction1(event); otherfunction1" />` for left clicks, and ... `<input onContextMenu="myfunction2(event); otherfunction2" />` for right clicks?

Comment: @user2811882: That's one solution, kinda.  `onClick` works with any type of click, whereas `onContextMenu` is for right-clicks only (when the context menu appears).

Comment: In that case, yes, I have tried this.  When I shift+right-click it just performs the shift+left-click function instead.  I'm not sure why.

Comment: @user2811882: How are you binding the other events?

Comment: @user2811882: You can try to use an `onclick` event for both.  Try `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(3)` for right-click.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Sorry I'm busy at work!  So... that brings me back to the original question.  Where do I put `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(3)` - can you edit your answer to show?

Comment: @user2811882: Updated answer.  Try that.

Comment: @user2811882: What is `Input.GetMouseButtonDown`?  `2` is used for right click when using `e.button`, but I'm not sure what value `Input.GetMouseButtonDown` uses.

Comment: Thanks for all the input, I was able to solve the problem with the other answer.